# Implemented a BottomNav Bar, but ran into internal compile erro and backEnd Internal Error

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, android-jetpack-compose

I tried to add bottomNavigation to my android Kotlin app but ran into large issues when trying to run the app. I can't compile the code nor can I preview the different screens.

Current Files:

Main Activity:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    lateinit var navController: NavHostController

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            FinFoTheme {
                MainScreen()

            }
        }
    }
}
```

BottomBarScreen:

```
sealed class BottomBarScreen(
    val route: String,
    val title: String,
    val icon: ImageVector
) {
    object Home: BottomBarScreen(
        route = "home",
        title = "Home",
        icon = Icons.Default.Home
    )
    object Detail: BottomBarScreen(
        route = "about",
        title = "About Us",
        icon = Icons.Default.Home // Use the Account icon
    )
}
```

MainScreen:

```
@SuppressLint("UnusedMaterial3ScaffoldPaddingParameter")
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun MainScreen() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    Scaffold(
        bottomBar = { BottomBar(navController = navController)}
    ) {
        BottomNavGraph(navController = navController)
    }
}

@Composable
fun BottomBar(navController: NavHostController) {
    val screens = listOf(
        BottomBarScreen.Home,
        BottomBarScreen.Detail,
    )
    val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
    val currentDestination = navBackStackEntry?.destination

    BottomAppBar {
        screens.forEach {screen ->
            AddItem(
                screen = screen,
                currentDestination = currentDestination,
                navController = navController
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun RowScope.AddItem(
    screen: BottomBarScreen,
    currentDestination: NavDestination?,
    navController: NavHostController
) {
    BottomNavigationItem(
        label = {
            Text(text = screen.title)
        },
        icon = {
            Icon(
                imageVector = screen.icon,
                contentDescription = "Navigation Icon"
            )
        },
        selected = currentDestination?.hierarchy?.any {
            it.route == screen.route
        } == true,
        onClick = {
            navController.navigate(screen.route)
        }
    )
}
```

BottomNavGraph:

```
@Composable
fun BottomNavGraph(navController: NavHostController) {
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = BottomBarScreen.Home.route
    ) {
        composable(route = BottomBarScreen.Home.route){
            HomeScreen()
        }
        composable(route = BottomBarScreen.Detail.route){
            DetailScreen()
        }
    }
}
```

Gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.finfo'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.finfo"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.3.2'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation platform('org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.8.0')
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.5.1'
    implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime-ktx:2.5.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest'

    implementation("androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material:material:1.4.3")
    android {
        buildFeatures {
            compose = true
        }

        composeOptions {
            kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.0"
        }

        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "1.8"
        }
    }


    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime-ktx:2.5.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.5.3'

    buildscript {
        ext {
            compose_ui_version = '1.3.3'
        }
    }
}
```

The errors stem from :app:compileDebugKotlin

Errors:
org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.BackendException: Backend Internal error: Exception during IR lowering:

```
org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.BackendException: Backend Internal error: Exception during IR lowering
File being compiled: /app/src/main/java/com/example/finfo/Screens/AboutScreen.kt
The root cause java.lang.RuntimeException was thrown at: org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generate(FunctionCodegen.kt:47)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.CodegenUtil.reportBackendException(CodegenUtil.kt:239)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.CodegenUtil.reportBackendException$default(CodegenUtil.kt:235)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.PerformByIrFilePhase.invokeSequential(performByIrFile.kt:68)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.PerformByIrFilePhase.invoke(performByIrFile.kt:55)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.PerformByIrFilePhase.invoke(performByIrFile.kt:41)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.NamedCompilerPhase.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.CompositePhase.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:29)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.NamedCompilerPhase.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.CompilerPhaseKt.invokeToplevel(CompilerPhase.kt:43)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory.invokeCodegen(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:305)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.runCodegen(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:356)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:134)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli$default(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:58)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:158)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:53)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:47)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:101)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:475)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:125)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:373)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally$default(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:318)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.rebuild(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:114)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileImpl(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:207)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:79)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:625)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:101)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1746)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor130.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:360)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:587)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:705)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:704)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception while generating code for:
FUN name:DetailScreen visibility:public modality:FINAL <> () returnType:kotlin.Unit
  annotations:
    Composable
  BLOCK_BODY
    CALL 'public final fun Box$default (modifier: androidx.compose.ui.Modifier?, contentAlignment: androidx.compose.ui.Alignment?, propagateMinConstraints: kotlin.Boolean, content: @[Composable] @[ExtensionFunctionType] kotlin.Function1<androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxScope, kotlin.Unit>, $mask0: kotlin.Int, $handler: kotlin.Any?): kotlin.Unit [inline] declared in androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxKt' type=kotlin.Unit origin=DEFAULT_DISPATCH_CALL
      modifier: CALL 'public final fun fillMaxSize$default (fraction: kotlin.Float, $mask0: kotlin.Int, $handler: kotlin.Any?): androidx.compose.ui.Modifier declared in androidx.compose.foundation.layout.SizeKt' type=androidx.compose.ui.Modifier origin=DEFAULT_DISPATCH_CALL
        $receiver: GET_FIELD 'FIELD FIELD_FOR_OBJECT_INSTANCE name:Companion type:androidx.compose.ui.Modifier.Companion visibility:public [final,static]' type=androidx.compose.ui.Modifier.Companion origin=null
        fraction: COMPOSITE type=kotlin.Float origin=DEFAULT_VALUE
          CONST Float type=kotlin.Float value=0.0
        $mask0: CONST Int type=kotlin.Int value=1
        $handler: CONST Null type=kotlin.Any? value=null
      contentAlignment: CALL 'public final fun <get-Center> (): androidx.compose.ui.Alignment declared in androidx.compose.ui.Alignment.Companion' type=androidx.compose.ui.Alignment origin=GET_PROPERTY
        $this: GET_FIELD 'FIELD FIELD_FOR_OBJECT_INSTANCE name:Companion type:androidx.compose.ui.Alignment.Companion visibility:public [final,static]' type=androidx.compose.ui.Alignment.Companion origin=null
      propagateMinConstraints: COMPOSITE type=kotlin.Boolean origin=DEFAULT_VALUE
        CONST Boolean type=kotlin.Boolean value=false
      content: BLOCK type=@[ExtensionFunctionType] kotlin.Function1<androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxScope, kotlin.Unit> origin=LAMBDA
        COMPOSITE type=kotlin.Unit origin=null
        FUNCTION_REFERENCE 'private final fun DetailScreen$lambda$0 (): kotlin.Unit declared in com.example.finfo.Screens.AboutScreenKt' type=@[ExtensionFunctionType] kotlin.Function1<androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxScope, kotlin.Unit> origin=INLINE_LAMBDA reflectionTarget=null
      $mask0: CONST Int type=kotlin.Int value=4
      $handler: CONST Null type=kotlin.Any? value=null

    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generate(FunctionCodegen.kt:47)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generate$default(FunctionCodegen.kt:41)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.ClassCodegen.generateMethodNode(ClassCodegen.kt:392)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.ClassCodegen.generateMethod(ClassCodegen.kt:409)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.ClassCodegen.generate(ClassCodegen.kt:152)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.FileCodegen.lower(JvmPhases.kt:44)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.FileLoweringPhaseAdapter.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:120)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.FileLoweringPhaseAdapter.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:116)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.NamedCompilerPhase.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.PerformByIrFilePhase.invokeSequential(performByIrFile.kt:65)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CompilationException: Back-end (JVM) Internal error: Couldn't inline method call: CALL 'public final fun Box$default (modifier: androidx.compose.ui.Modifier?, contentAlignment: androidx.compose.ui.Alignment?, propagateMinConstraints: kotlin.Boolean, content: @[Composable] @[ExtensionFunctionType] kotlin.Function1<androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxScope, kotlin.Unit>, $mask0: kotlin.Int, $handler: kotlin.Any?): kotlin.Unit [inline] declared in androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxKt' type=kotlin.Unit origin=DEFAULT_DISPATCH_CALL
Method: null
File is unknown
The root cause java.lang.IllegalStateException was thrown at: org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.inline.SourceCompilerForInlineKt.getMethodNode(SourceCompilerForInline.kt:118)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.inline.InlineCodegen.performInline(InlineCodegen.kt:63)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.IrInlineCodegen.genInlineCall(IrInlineCodegen.kt:163)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.IrInlineCallGenerator$DefaultImpls.genCall(IrInlineCallGenerator.kt:31)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.IrInlineCodegen.genCall(IrInlineCodegen.kt:34)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitCall(ExpressionCodegen.kt:529)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitCall(ExpressionCodegen.kt:136)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrCall.accept(IrCall.kt:25)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitStatementContainer(ExpressionCodegen.kt:464)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitBlockBody(ExpressionCodegen.kt:468)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitBlockBody(ExpressionCodegen.kt:136)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrBlockBody.accept(IrBlockBody.kt:24)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.generate(ExpressionCodegen.kt:242)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.FunctionCodegen.doGenerate(FunctionCodegen.kt:118)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generate(FunctionCodegen.kt:45)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: couldn't find inline method Landroidx/compose/foundation/layout/BoxKt;.Box$default(Landroidx/compose/ui/Modifier;Landroidx/compose/ui/Alignment;ZLkotlin/jvm/functions/Function1;ILjava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.inline.SourceCompilerForInlineKt.getMethodNode(SourceCompilerForInline.kt:118)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.inline.SourceCompilerForInlineKt.loadCompiledInlineFunction(SourceCompilerForInline.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.IrSourceCompilerForInline.compileInlineFunction(IrSourceCompilerForInline.kt:92)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.inline.InlineCodegen.performInline(InlineCodegen.kt:47)
    ... 63 more
```

Internal compiler error. See log for more details:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
   > Internal compiler error. See log for more details
```

I tried using different gradle verisons or trying to update the compiler version but it didn't work nor did any attempts at using different gradle implementations.